# Allow questions to be pulled between sites, as well as being pushed

Tags: feature-request

As it stands at present, when questions are asked on the "wrong" site, it has to be pushed off to the correct site, this is asymmetric, as there is no way to pull questions from the "wrong" site to the "correct one"

Let's say that I come across a question, like [this one on SU](https://superuser.com/questions/15742/how-to-view-a-pages-source-when-a-javascript-modal-popup-loads-first) that I think may get a better response on SO. Given I don't have a huge SU rep yet, I'm unable to vote to close as "Belongs on Stack Overflow" (sure, I can add a comment)

Comment: The example you post is a bad one, as the question is about functionality in Firefox. It is not directly related to a programming issue, although the functionality is something a programmer might have better knowledge of than other users. On SO, it would probably be closed as off topic, or sent back to SU!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a pseudo-pull mechanism.  If flag the question as requiring moderator attention, you can type in the box that the question belongs on another site.  Then, through the magic of computers, it will evaluated and migrated by the Moderatron 4000.  Be sure to mention your rep on the other site; the Moderatron *loves* superfluous detail (especially the instance running on the server "Marc Gravell").

Comment: Maybe I underuse "flag", as I'd only flag something that was abusive or spam and doesn't belong on *any* site...

Comment: The moderators are there for a reason: to do our bidding.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to allow users to vote to close as "Belongs on ..." if they have sufficient rep on the target site, so, in the example above, as I can vote to close on SO, I could be given the option to vote to close as "Belongs on Stack Overflow" across the family of sites (where I have correctly linked my accounts, of course)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a high enough rep on SU, it could theoretically be said that the system doesn't trust you enough to know what does and doesn't belong on SU.

With that said, I think the added benefit vs. the complexity to implement makes it not worth the while. Especially considering if you don't have the appropriate rep to close a question, the close menu doesn't even show up for you, so I don't see how this would work at all without going and mucking that up as well.